# Rendering very big amount of html elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i have an array that includes 700000 JS objects having some data. I want to use the data of that objects to create 700000 html elements that show that data onclick. I just want to know the fastest way to create so much elements

I have tried two ways -
Firstly, I have tried to use document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML += "" and connect eventListener

It worked really slow

Secondly, I have tried to use document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(myNode)

This option was much faster, but still was slow on phones and weak computers

If you know more efficient way, please write it

Comment: The actually efficient way is using "virtual scrolling" when the elements are instantiated only after you scroll down to them. In your case, just make a pagination which shows 100-1000 elements at once

Comment: Is precompiling the html an option?

Comment: @Dimava that sounds good, in that case i just need to place empty element to see if it's in the view?

Comment: @spirift I don't know this term, can you explain please?

Comment: Basically making the HTML server-side instead of client-side. However, for millions of records, it would be very inefficient.

Comment: No that's not what I meant, sorry I should have been more clear. Essentially you could render the page, then save the html in a new file, then serve it up as plain html. Tools like nextjs can help with this. I'll try and write up an answer soon.

Comment: @spirift, i think that could be not bad, but file will be too big. And sadly, some browsers ignore very huge files.